# Finding all dictionary that meets the parameter of a sub-dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a Python list called `data` and a Python dictionary called `search_parameter`. My question is how do I get a python program to return the dictionary in data that meets the details in search_parameter. I'm using python3.9 if it helps. Thanks in advance for any help.

data

```
[
    {
        "id": "GXnWSLFa",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@email.com",
        "contact": "91111111",
        "mmp": 49.9
    },
    {
        "id": "ivVpvA8X",
        "firstname": "Alan",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "email": "alansmith@email.com",
        "contact": "81111111",
        "mmp": 19.9
    }
]
```

search_parameter

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: will the search parameters be limited to `firstname` and `lastname`?

Comment: @illusion the search parameter is not limited to firstname and lastname, it could be any keys in the dictionary in data list.

Comment: also, do you want to make a function or something? or is it procedural?

Comment: @illusion yes, I like to make a function. I also saw your answer. It was exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this...

```py
def search(params):
    for x in data:
        found = True
        for param in params:
            if params[param] != x[param]:
                found = False
                break
        if found:
            return x
    return None
```

you can call it like: `search(search_parameters)`

This will return the block only if all the parameters provided in the search match. You can also provide any no of parameters, it will provide the first matched value. If none match, then it will return `None`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I found:

```
def search(params):
    searchThreshold = len(params)
    currentMatches = 0
    for d in data:
        if currentMatches != searchThreshold:
            for param in params:
                if param[key] == d.get(key):
                    currentMatches += 1
            if currentMatches == searchThreshold:
                    return(d)
```

This only returns the dict if all parameters are found.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for block in data:
    if block['firstname'] == search_parameter['firstname']:
       return block
```

of course you can validate it also by `lastname` key.